# Can't send mail using Kmail

Tags: d-bus, kmail

I'm using KDE on debian.

On *Kmail* application, while sending a mail I got the following error:

> Failed to get D-Bus interface of `mailfilteragent`.

But, inbox is synchronized properly. Previously, I had 2 problems regarding this app; now it reduced to one. Use it as this is lightweight than **Thunderbird, Mailspring**. Weeks ago, I used the *Mailspring* app, the only problem is it sends the message twice.

So, Is there any solution?

Comment: Try restarting Akonadi. If the issue persists, I'd try to re-install https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/kdepim

Comment: `akonadictl restart` should restart akonadi

Comment: @rubaiat : now it's working! may be some _PIM_ modules were uninstalled or cleaned or broken at that time!